# How to limit number of requests waiting in queue in HikariCP?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, queue, hikaricp

Let's imagine we have x open connections to the db, but the number of queries in the queue is much larger than we can process. Is there a way in hikari to limit queue size, so not to overload our connection pool? Something like we would decline those queries right away without waiting for connection timeout?
I went through all hikari configs and didn't find anything similar. Is there any solution how can I implement this?

Comment: you can put low `connectionTimeout` value so the wait is minimal